# Trouble interpreting this little text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The headine is:

> "Trump Campaign Chief to Headline Jan. 6 Hearing on Election Lies"

I get headline is being used as verb, But I can't interpret this, is it like saying:

"Trump Campaign Chief" will show up in headlines? Like he is going to make the headlines?

The way it is writen to me seems like he is the one contriving the headline. Which one is it?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/headline check out the third definition of the verb. It means to be the main performer.

Answer (score 1):

> "Trump Campaign Chief to Headline Jan. 6 Hearing on Election Lies"

This is a journalistic headline (in a different meaning of headline - the bold text at the top of the page or story) and is shorthand for

> Bill Stepien, (?) who was Trump's campaign chief, will be the main witness {headlines}
> in front of  the House committee investigating the Jan. 6 attack on
> the U.S. Capitol. In the 2nd day of the hearings they intend to focus on Election Lies

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I believe "headline" is being used in a way similar to how it might in a place like Las Vegas, where "to headline" means to appear as one of the stars in a show.

Here is an example ([source](https://www.ticketnews.com/2022/06/travis-scott-sza-j-cole-to-headline-day-n-vegas-festival-in-september/)):

> Travis Scott, SZA, J. Cole to Headline Day N Vegas Festival in September

Perhaps the writer of the headline you presented is trying to hint that the Jan. 6 hearing has some of the qualities of a stage show.